# Retrieving issuer of a X509Certificate2 object

Tags: c#, .net, certificate, x509certificate

I have a [X509Certificate2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2(v=vs.110).aspx) object retrieved from X509Store. I want to get the issuer of this certificate but the only two properties that this object offers are [X509Certificate2.Issuer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate.issuer(v=vs.110).aspx) and [X509Certificate2.IssuerName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.issuername(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) where `.Issuer` is kinda misleading as it returs string that is basically issuer's name.

Both those properties can at most return a [Distinguished Name](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366101(v=vs.85).aspx) but DNs are not unique, right? Therefore I don't want to use [X509Certificate2Collection.Find](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2collection.find(v=vs.110).aspx) method with [X509FindType.FindByIssuerDistinguishedName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509findtype(v=vs.110).aspx) flag.

How can I get a certificate's issuer and be sure I have the "right one". Note: I don't have to use X509Certificate2 object. Alternatives are welcome.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you have a certificate and you want to find the issuer certificate. This can be done as follows:

1. Check if the leaf certificate's Subject and Issuer fields are not the same. Otherwise, the certificate is the issuer (self-signed certificate)
2. Instantiate [`X509Chain`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509chain) object and pass leaf certificate to [`X509Chain.Build`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509chain.build) method. Examine [`ChainElements`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509chain.chainelements) property (a collection) and element at index 1 is the issuer.

   ```
    using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

    namespace Name {
        class Class1 {
            public static X509Certificate2 GetIssuer(X509Certificate2 leafCert) {
                if (leafCert.Subject == leafCert.Issuer) { return leafCert; }
                X509Chain chain = new X509Chain();
                chain.ChainPolicy.RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.NoCheck;
                chain.Build(leafCert);
                X509Certificate2 issuer = null;
                if (chain.ChainElements.Count > 1) {
                    issuer = chain.ChainElements[1].Certificate;
                }
                return issuer;
            }
        }
    }
   ```

   Note that this only works if the issuer certificate is in the user or machine certificate store.

Comment: That was it! X509Chain was the solution.

Comment: This only works if you've got access to the issuer certificate.